# Javadoc custom taglets in Java 11

Tags: javadoc, taglet

Is it possible to create programmatic taglets in Java 11 anymore?  It appears com.sun.tools.doclets.Taglet has been removed after Java 8 and any documentation I find online for creating taglets refer exclusively to Java 8.  I've been stuck using Java 8 for building just our Javadocs.

The documentation for the "new" javadoc framework is seriously lacking compared to the old framework.  It's almost like they got rid of the old stuff before they fully completed the new and then the new stuff got abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by implementing `jdk.javadoc.doclet.Taglet`. See the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/Taglet.html).

You have to implement the `toString(List<? extends DocTree> tags, Element element)` method. There you can return you custom text/html which is then inserted into the generated Javadoc at the respective place.